# My Domain shows under construction in google search

Tags: reactjs, heroku, subdomain, hosting

When I uploaded the site to the domain and shows the given details in google search.

Can anyone tell me why does it happen and how to solve this.

My actual hosting process is Heroku as free dynos

[image: Here is the details shows in google]

Answer (score 0):

hey it Looks your website needs time to be crawled and indexed by google algorithm. it may take some time so just wait i guess